# PartilSign VersionedTransaction

Tags: web3.js, transactions, versionedtransactions

I using old Transactions, and use partialSign. First sign on client then sign on servier. Now want to migrate to v0 transactions.
Is exists way to partialSign VersionedTransaction ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found methods addSignature (its new methods, did not present before). First I sign transaction and then use addSignature for add signatures, that I received from client.

Answer (score 0):

These are all viable ways to sign a Versioned Transaction:

```
    let tx = new VersionedTransaction(message);
    tx.sign([wallet.payer]);
    tx.addSignature(wallet.publicKey, signature);
```